# Does it make sense for the backend server to be built in 2 or more different languages / frameworks?

Tags: web, server, backend

So for example, can the backend of a web app be built in both Django and NodeJS? Does this question even make sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple frameworks each serving a different purposes for the same web app. For example Django could be the primary framework but you need node to provide other services for the app.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @ganidat You may have a primary framework like Django and you may prefer to use Node to provide supplementary services to the app, it could even be an existing Node app on a different server. There has to be a reason why you'll need Node, it could be something that can't be done with Django.